# How can I use RetroFit2 responseBodyConverter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to use RetroFit's `responseBodyConverter()` but I'm having some trouble, I'm expected to pass `java.lang.annoatation.annoatation` as the second parameter, but Kotlin suggests against that and says to use `Kotlin.Annotation`. I'm unsure of how to do that. Can someone provide an example of `responseBodyConverter()` in Kotlin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@bluecup` in the AndroidChat slack channel has led me to the correct answer. I ended up doing the following:

`Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(<T>, arrayOfNulls<Annotation>(0))`

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Where can I find that slack channel ;)